# How to make PostgresQL use environment variables from .env file after re-creating the container (without removing the volume)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

There is a message in [Docker PostgresQL docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you
>   start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
>   pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

So when I recreate my postgres container with `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans`, it throws me errors like:

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"

It happens because postgres sees that there is the volume, so it skips all scripts and .env files (where I set `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`).

**How this can be solved? (I mean provide vars from .env file everytime I re-create postgres container)**

p.s. It is impossible for me to delete old volume as I have data there.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - "./init/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - "./data/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:       ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER:     ${POSTGRES_USR}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PWD}
```

My .env file:

```
# Postgres
export POSTGRES_USR="someuser"
export POSTGRES_PWD="somepwd"
export POSTGRES_DB="somedb"
export POSTGRES_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USR}:${POSTGRES_PWD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `POSTGRES_*` environment variables are used to define the way that the databases get created and connected.  If you have an existing database, you need to [define the `PG*` environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) so that you can connect to it.

Therefore, you should also include `PGPASSWORD` in the `.env` file, so that the password that you have defined for the existing cluster will get added to the environment:

```
$ cat .env
...
PGPASSWORD="somepwd"
```

Otherwise, you can [include a `.pgpass` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) in `/home/postgres`

BTW, the `.env` file should just be a list of key-value pairs.  You don't need to `export` them:

```
$ cat .env
POSTGRES_USER="someuser"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="somepwd"
POSTGRES_DB="somedb"
POSTGRES_URL="postgres://${POSTGRES_USR}:${POSTGRES_PWD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable"
```

Answer (score 1):

in my problem, I remove `"` from the Postgres config in `.env` file , this solved my issues

```
POSTGRES_USR=someuser
POSTGRES_PWD=somepwd
POSTGRES_DB=somedb
```

and in docker-compose file

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_DB:       ${POSTGRES_DB}
  POSTGRES_USER:     ${POSTGRES_USR}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PWD}
```